# Scrapy crawler ignores `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` when run as a script

Tags: python, scrapy

I'd like to acquire data, using [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), from a few different sites and perform some analysis on that data. Since the both the crawlers and the code to analyze the data relate to the same project, I'd like to store everything in the same Git repository. I created a [minimal reproducible example on Github](https://github.com/alexwoolford/scrapyStackoverflowQuestion).

The structure of the project looks like this:

```
./crawlers
./crawlers/__init__.py
./crawlers/myproject
./crawlers/myproject/__init__.py
./crawlers/myproject/myproject
./crawlers/myproject/myproject/__init__.py
./crawlers/myproject/myproject/items.py
./crawlers/myproject/myproject/pipelines.py
./crawlers/myproject/myproject/settings.py
./crawlers/myproject/myproject/spiders
./crawlers/myproject/myproject/spiders/__init__.py
./crawlers/myproject/myproject/spiders/example.py
./crawlers/myproject/scrapy.cfg
./scrapyScript.py
```

From the `./crawlers/myproject` folder, I can execute the crawler by typing:

```
scrapy crawl example
```

The crawler uses some downloader middleware, specifically, [alecxe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) excellent [scrapy-fake-useragent](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-fake-useragent). From `settings.py`:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}
```

When executed using `scrapy crawl ...` the useragent looks like a real browser. Here's a sample record from a webserver:

```
24.8.42.44 - - [16/Jun/2015:05:07:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 27161 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Looking at the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html), it's possible to do the equivalent of a `scrapy crawl ...` from a script. The `scrapyScript.py` file, which is based on the documentation, looks like this:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals

from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from crawlers.myproject.myproject.spiders.example import ExampleSpider

spider = ExampleSpider()
settings = get_project_settings()

crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)

crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

When I execute the script, I can see that the crawler makes page requests. Unfortunately, it is ignoring the `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES`. The useragent, for example, is no longer spoofed:

```
24.8.42.44 - - [16/Jun/2015:05:32:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 27161 "-" "Scrapy/0.24.6 (+http://scrapy.org)"
```

Somehow, when the crawler is executed from a script, it seems to be ignoring the settings in `settings.py`.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using `settings.cfg` or `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes, try putting your custom settings in `settings.py`.

Comment: My mistake, @marven. `settings.cfg` points to `settings.py` and does not contain the `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` dict as I'd previous stated in the question. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `get_project_settings()` to find the desired `settings.py`, set the [`SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE`environment variable](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=scrapy_settings_module#designating-the-settings):

```
import os
import sys

# ...

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.curdir, "crawlers/myproject"))
os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

settings = get_project_settings()
```

Note that, due to the location of your runner script, you need to add `myproject` to the `sys.path`. Or, move `scrapyScript.py` under `myproject` directory.